# How to redirect into a specific page variant

Tags: panels, redirection, chaos-tool-suite

I installed panels, page manager, ctools and page manager redirect.

I made a (panel) page say foo1
- admin/structure/pages/add with variant type Panel. In this I put 5 variants named foo1variant1, foo1variant2, foo1variant3, foo1variant4, foo1variant5,

I also setup a page manager redirect say foo2:
- admin/structure/pages/add with variant type redirect.
In the end I should give the url it should go to foo1 en into foo1variant3, .

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Variants on the same Page always have the same URL.  The variant that is shown is determined by the selection criteria.

If the selection criteria for Variant 1 fails, it moves on to Variant 2.

If the selection criteria for Variant 2 also fails, then it will try to show Variant 3.

The only exception to the 'same URL' rule is if you have optional Arguments (that start with `!` instead of `%`) in which case you can have a url of `foo` and `foo/bar` handled by the same page.